# azure CLI not failing when it should

Tags: azure-cli

I use azure cli task to create some azure resources, for example:

```
- job: provision_job
  steps:        
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: Create app service plan, site, keyvault and appinsight
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.azureSubscriptionName }}'
        scriptType: ps
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          
          az appservice plan create --name '${{ parameters.servicePlanName }}' -g ${{ parameters.groupName }} --sku ${{ parameters.servicePlanNameSKU }}
          
          az webapp create -g ${{ parameters.groupName }} -p "${{ parameters.servicePlanName }}" -n "${{ parameters.webAppName }}"  --runtime '${{ parameters.webAppRuntime }}' --assign-identity [system] --tags ${{ parameters.tags }}
          
          az keyvault create --location ${{ parameters.keyvaultLocation}} --name ${{ parameters.keyvaultName}} --resource-group ${{ parameters.groupName }} --enable-soft-delete=true
                          
          az resource create --resource-group ${{ parameters.groupName }} --resource-type "Microsoft.Insights/components" --name ${{ parameters.appInsightName }} --location ${{ parameters.appInsightLocation }} --properties '{\"Application_Type\":\"web\"}'
```

When keyvault creation fails, the log will print an error saying `The Vault 'xxx' not found within subscription`, however, the task succeeded. debug log says:

```
##[debug]$LASTEXITCODE: 0
2021-09-09T09:49:15.2655965Z ##[debug]Exit code 0 received from tool 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
2021-09-09T09:49:15.2656808Z ##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
```

So looks like if some az command fails in the middle, power shell somehow can't detect it? I tried to set failOnStderr to true, but it won't work as any warning message from AZ command let will be treated as a failure.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, by default, the line `if ((Test-Path -LiteralPath variable:\\LASTEXITCODE)) { exit $LASTEXITCODE }` is appended to the end of your script. This will cause the last exit code from an external command to be propagated as the exit code of PowerShell. So if the last command succeeds despite the intermediate `az` commands failing, it does not fail the task.

Handling errors with Azure CLI commands within a PS evironment can be a little tricky. While running Azure CLI commands on PowerShell, I've found that checking on the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#section-1) `$?` helps in determining the execution status of the command effectively, as follows:

```
# Returns False as the command errors out
PS C:\> $output = az group create -g myRG | ConvertFrom-Json
if (!$?) {
    Write-Error "Error creating resource group"
}
else {
    Write-Output "RG created"
}

az : ERROR: the following arguments are required: --location/-l
At line:2 char:11

####

# Returns True as the command succeeds
PS C:\> $output = az group create -g myRG -l eastus | ConvertFrom-Json
if (!$?) {
    Write-Error "Error creating resource group"
}
else {
    Write-Output "RG created"
}

RG created
```

The same check can be applied to your Azure CLI commands as well enabling `failOnStandardError` at the task level.

> I tried to set `failOnStderr` to true, but it won't work as any warning message from AZ cmdlet will be treated as a failure.

To make Azure CLI suppress warnings and [only show errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-configuration#cli-configuration-values-and-environment-variables) during command invocation, you could use the `--only-show-errors` parameter so that only errors will be written to `stderr`, suppressing warnings from preview, deprecated and experimental commands. Be sure to set [powerShellErrorActionPreference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops#task-inputs) (Azure CLI task input that translates to PowerShell's `$ErrorActionPreference` variable) to `Stop` though.

```
# Can be set within the script or at the Task level
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$output = az group create -g myRG --only-show-errors | ConvertFrom-Json
if (!$?) {
    Write-Error "Error creating resource group"
}
else {
    Write-Output "RG created"
}

# Change it back to the old value
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
```

**Edit:**
Check [Error handling for Azure CLI in PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively#error-handling-for-azure-cli-in-powershell) for guidance about handling errors with Azure CLI commands in PS environments.